# Can Prometheus be used to build anomaly detection graphs? If yes, what metrics should be used - Counters, Gauge, Histograms, Summary?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, anomaly-detection

Have a data set that has been aggregated using the Prohpet Fourier ML anomaly algorithm containing timestamps,yhat,yhat_lower,yhat_upper,fact. How to have this data added to Prometheus to generate an Anomaly detection graph. A graph that shows upper and lower bounds, shows the actual data all in the same graph. Can grafana be used to visualize such a graph?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to covert the data to Prometheus OpenMetrics format before data ingestion and then import it into Prometheus. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#backfilling-from-openmetrics-format).